# PL\SQL Функция не выводит текст

Tags: plsql

помогите пожалуйста, функция должна выводить либо номер телефона либо текст 'Нет телефона', телефон выводит а текст нет, помогите разобраться что не так :(

````
return VARCHAR2 is
pnumber VARCHAR2(100);
begin  
select case when max(b.phone_number) is null then 'Нет телефона'
else max(b.phone_number) end
into pnumber
from PERSONS a
left join phones b
on a.personid=b.personid 
where b.personid=abc 
group by a.name;
return (pnumber);
end;```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Можете привести, пожалуйста, примерное представление того, что имеет ваш `PERSONS` и `phones`

Comment: Acinit, PERSONS это таблица с сотрудниками, phones это таблица с их номерами телефонов

Comment: `MAX` игнорирует `NULL`, но есть рецепты, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418250/8324991

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто написать запрос вида:

```
select 
  case when b.phone_number is null then 'Нет телефона'
  else b.phone_number end
```

group by тогда не понадобится. И в return скобочки можно удалить у (pnumber).